# How can I download desktop version of unicorn 14.10 without torrent

Tags: downloads, 14.10, .desktop

I cannot find any copy of ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso that I can download without using torrent.  Can someone give me a URL for this.

Comment: why can't you use a torrent? not like it's illegal or anything...

Comment: Have you considered checking the Ubuntu site itself?  It has a download link right there that is over HTTP and not a torrent

Answer (score 2):

You can download without using torrent, From this link:

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```